# expo run:android Error: Cannot find native module 'ExpoImage', js engine: hermes`

Tags: react-native, expo, expo-image-picker

No idea what's going on it's working on web, expo-image is installed

```
  Error: Cannot find native module 'ExpoImage', js engine: hermes 
    at ContextNavigator (http://192.168.1.14:8081/node_modules/expo-router/entry.bundle//&platform=android&dev=true&hot=false&lazy=true&transform.engine=hermes&transform.bytecode=true&transform.routerRoot=app:149634:24)
    at ExpoRoot (http://192.168.1.14:8081/node_modules/expo-router/entry.bundle//&platform=android&dev=true&hot=false&lazy=true&transform.engine=hermes&transform.bytecode=true&transform.routerRoot=app:149590:28)
    at App
    at ErrorToastContainer (http://192.168.1.14:8081/node_modules/expo-router/entry.bundle//&platform=android&dev=true&hot=false&lazy=true&transform.engine=hermes&transform.bytecode=true&transform.routerRoot=app:335132:24)
    at ErrorOverlay
```